# Solve Using KKT Conditions

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I need to minimize the function $c = 5x^2-80x+y^2-32y$, subject to the

constraints $x,y≥0$ and $x+y≥20$ using KKT Conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following: 

 - first you write the Lagrangian:

 $L = 5x^2−80x+y^2−32y - l_1 x - l_2 y - m (x+y-20)$

 - then you solve the following system: 

 $ DL/Dx = 10 x -80-l_1-m = 0$

 $ DL/Dy = 2 y -32 -l_2 -m = 0$

 $ DL/Dl_1 = -x <= 0$

 $ DL/Dl_2 = -y <= 0$

 $ DL/Dm = 20-x-y <= 0$

 $l_1, l_2,m >=0$

 $l_1 x =0$

 $l_2 y = 0$

 $m (x + y - 20) = 0$

 The solution should be: $x = 8, y= 16, l_1=l_2=m=0, f(x,y)=-576$.

So in this case the contraints are not binding.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry! It was just 5x^2! How much will that change anything other than the solution?

Comment: Is this a binding constraint? Why?

Comment: I changed the solution with the new function. This time constraints aren't binding.